# ansible loop json which is object to extract its key and values and search and replace in file

Tags: json, search, replace, ansible

I try to loop simple JSON which is a JSON object

```
{
    ${foo1}:somevalue1,
    ${foo2}:somevalue2,
    ${zoo1}:somevalue111,
    ${zoo2}:somevalue222
}
```

Loading This JSON to set_fact which work great

```
- name: set fact
      set_fact:
         multi_apps: "{{ AAA| to_json }}"
```

Now I like to iterate over the key/value of the JSON object and search and replace it in the file

For example, if i have in the file

```
app1: ${foo1}
app2: ${foo2}
```

it will replace to

```
app1: somevalue1
app2: somevalue2
```

Comment: 1) your first code example is not a valid json. 2) `to_json` transforms an in memory data structure to a json string representation. What you would want to use here (providing your file is a valid json representation) is `from_json` 3) This entire question looks like you are reinventing jinja2 templating. Why don't you use ansible the way it is supposed to be ? => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/b4daf6f3e2f6abdc5ade61abb11cec5c

Comment: It's a duplicate of your own question. You should test the code and post [mre] if something goes wrong.